# Word for explaining something cruelly

Tags: single-word-requests, speech

I'm looking for something to describe speech that is something along the lines of cruel, menacing, tormenting, and dripping with malicious meaning. But not quite outright threatening, i.e. not "I'm gonna kill you", but more:

> "You'll be the scapegoat for this and there's nothing you can do about it," the villain _________.

Comment: 'The villain _sneered_'?

Comment: *The villain said*. If you can't make the villain's dialogue drip with malice no verb or adjective tacked onto the sentence will.  But this is probably writing advice, and off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "You'll be the scapegoat for this and there's nothing you can do about
> it," the villain **jeered**.

**jeer** (v.)

> To speak or cry out with derision or mockery [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jeer)

> Make rude and mocking remarks, typically in a loud voice. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/jeer)

---

> He let Barry go with a threat “Tell anyone and I'll come to your room
> one night,” he **jeered** into the boy's face, “and kill you! [R. J.
> King; *Sylvia Rose*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sylvia_Rose/Siat8mPJJsYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=I%27ll%20kill%20%22he%20jeered%22&pg=PA188&printsec=frontcover)

> When he dismissed everyone else, he **jeered** in my face, "I'm going
> to run you down. I'll make you hang or shoot yourself just like the
> other soldiers who crossed me." [J. Bardach and K. Glesson; *Man is
> Wolf to Man: Surviving the Gulag*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Man_Is_Wolf_to_Man/atqE2B5UiCoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=I%27ll%20kill%20%22he%20jeered%22&pg=PA216&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 2):

One of the verbs nowadays accepted as expressive quotative verbs is **gloat**.

> Private First Class Bradley Manning may have done a first-class
> disservice to US international relations, but by allegedly copying
> classified files on to a CD, he has changed not just the course of
> history, but how it will be written.
>
> “I listened and lip-synched to Lady Gaga’s Telephone while
> ‘exfiltrating’ possibly the largest data spillage in American
> history,” he gloated after this feast of raw, contemporary history was
> pitched into the public domain. Centuries hence, historians will still
> be citing the Manning hoard.

[[Ben MacIntyre; The Times; Nov 30 2010](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/to-ctrl-wikileaks-will-mean-more-del-n3gnldhj6lf)]

> "This is called the old game of keeping the headmaster in," he gloated.

[[Peter Symonds College](https://www.psc.ac.uk/history)]

This is an extended usage, the prototypical intransitive verb, obviously with closely related meaning, being defined:

> **gloat** [verb] [no object]:
>
> Dwell on ... another's misfortune with smugness or
> malignant pleasure.

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/gloat)]

Kate Bunting suggests another equally acceptable modern quotative verb (*sneer*).

Visser describes this phenomenon (and a further development):

> Transitivisation [of verbs] may also have been furthered by the
> fashion which set in in later modern English – especially in novels –
> of treating verbs expressing human and animal sounds (such as *bellow,
> coo* and *groan*) as well as verbs such as *smirk, smile* and
> *persist* as if they were synonyms of *say* by giving them the quoted words as object [ie using novel quotative verbs]. From
>
> - She smiled “I don’t believe you”
>
> and
>
> - He grunted “I thank you”
>
> to
>
> - She smiled disbelief
>
> and
>
> - He grunted his gratitude
>
> was only a step.

[An historical syntax of the English language; Vol 1 part 3; F T Visser] [reformatted]

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> "You'll be the scapegoat for this and there's nothing you can do about it," the villain laughed.

The reader would then assume evilness.

Answer (score 0):

Phrase: 'It's your funeral'

Meaning: If someone says to you 'It's your funeral', they think your decision or your actions will have bad consequences for you.

Example: It's your funeral if you gamble.

Comment: "It's your funeral" doesn't really carry the "cruel, menacing, tormenting, and dripping with malicious meaning" that the question requires. It's usually said to try to prevent a bad outcome by suggesting that the person might like to re-think their decision.

Answer (score 0):

Condescend, or condescension.
I must admit, though, “Jeered” is a pretty good one
Oxford English Dictionary defines it as:

con·de·scend
/ˌkändəˈsend/
Learn to pronounce
verb
past tense: condescended; past participle: condescended
show feelings of superiority; be patronizing.
"take care not to condescend to your reader"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The villains in formulaic fiction also like to **cackle**.  It means to laugh in a manner that resembles the loud call of a bird.